How to optimize my SharePoint on prem site if multiple sites are created for each case
I'm working on SharePoint 2016. When a web service is called from Dynamics CRM (imagine through some button click), a new SharePoint site is created under a site collection(mentioned in my base SharePoint configuration list). Like that for different items on Dynamics, individual SP 2016 site is created which has some lists, documents. Do we have any alternative solution to optimize my SharePoint site or for instead of creating new SharePoint site each time.
Thank you in advance
